# MassTransit & RabbitMQ - How to verify that messaged got processed inside of containerized consumer?

Tags: rabbitmq, containers, integration-testing, masstransit

I am working on integration tests for my project.
I have containerized RabbitMQ queue, containerized consumer of this queue (using MassTransit) and containerized API that this consumer calls during processing of the message.

My test pushes a message to the queue, it gets picked up by the consumer and here is where my problem comes in - **is there a way to check when this consumer inside of container proccesed the message, from my test perspective?**
For now I just used `Thread.Sleep()` for 10 seconds and run my assertions after that.
It works but, obviously, as the number of tests grow this is becoming tedious...

Answer (score 1):

How about using the actual rabbitmq REST API for that? From an integration test, you could use basic authentication, and query the queue endpoint, e. g.

```
/api/queues/%2F/foo
```

to query the queue `foo` on the default virtual host `/` (url-encoded as %2F). This will give you back a JSON data structure with the same details that you can see via the UI (in fact the UI is using this API as well), like the below (heavily truncated).

```
{
    "messages": 1,
    "messages_ready": 1,
    "messages_unacknowledged": 0
}
```

You can poll this endpoint until `messages` is equal to 0.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea. I have opted for other approach that I will mention in my own answer. But I think I like your approach even more

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I eventually resolved this:

I didn't mention that I also have Seq server running as I didn't think it would be relevant in my case but turned out it was.
At the end of message consuming method I have put log that I have enriched with custom property that indicates that this log means that message has been processed. Then in my integration test I set Polly policy that asks Seq for this "processing finished" log (with correct message id of course) until it appears (or until set timeout). However, I feel like @Driedas answer is way simpler

Answer (score -2):

Maybe this can help you

https://event-driven.io/en/testing_asynchronous_processes_with_a_little_help_from_dotnet_channels/

Allows for awaiting rabbitmq events from within the tests without doing thread.Sleep

Comment: Channels are in-process, and would be of no use here.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).